# Downsize EC2 from M3 Large to M3 medium to minimize cost

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have 25k+ users per day now and I am on `m3.large` instance. I have used almost 370GB bandwidth in November, 2015. I need to serve 25k ~ 40k people everyday in the next two years ( rough estimation).

**BUT** 
I need to downsize my cost for EC2 which is $141 to $146 per month now. For that I am willing to downgrade my instance to `m3.medium` which is half the capacity of `m3.large`.

I need to know with the current access rate and bandwidth usage can I downgrade my capacity as `m3.medium` and survive for next two years with 25k ~ 40k users?

**FYI** I have installed and been using all the in premise services like

- Apache 2.4
- MySQL 5.6
- Memcached 1.1

Comment: Have you considered using [Reserved Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/)?

Comment: Nope. That's not suitable for us.

Comment: Entirely dependent on your app, eg if you are experiencing high CPU usage then switching to a smaller instance is probably a bad plan. For what it's worth I have always found m3.medium instances to be rather slow - definitely doesn't behave like half an m3.large

Comment: Thanks @FrederickCheung

Answer (score 1):

Consider use Auto Scaling and Load Balancing.  It permits cheapest instances with verticalization to gain. Remember: "As pay as you go". Your verticalization parameters will define when new instance is started.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. We already tried downsizing and it did not go well. The site had become irresponsible with even 200 concurrent requests. Later we again restored it to m3.large. We now by experiment know that for our kinda system m3.large works for the time being.